# Unable to find object at PDF cross-reference stream location. (abcpdf)

Tags: abcpdf

I am getting below error when processing the single page pdf.

May i know why i am getting this error

Doc theSrc = new Doc();
theSrc.Read(e.FullPath); on this line

Unable to find object at PDF cross-reference stream location.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ABCpdf's ExtraChecks feature that would give you the option to either try and get ABCpdf to fix the corruption, or have your own application/site issue a warning that the PDF is corrupt.

Of course there are limits to what ABCpdf can fix - in that case you would still end receiving an error from ABCpdf.

In terms of code, the logic would be something like this:

```
                try
                {
                    doc.Read(inFile);
                    // No corruption detected
                    doc.Save("good.pdf");
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        doc.Read(inFile, new XReadOptions { ExtraChecks = true });
                        // ExtraChecks managed to fix the corruption
                        doc.Save("fixed.pdf"));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // ABCpdf could not fix the corruption
                    }
                }
```